# Openseadragon plug missing some types

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, openseadragon, openseadragon-plugin

I was converting [OpenSeadragonFiltering](https://github.com/usnistgov/OpenSeadragonFiltering) in to typescript types with some extra filter options. Unfortunately, there are some filter types are missing when extending the props in to filters.

```
declare module "openseadragon" {
  interface Filters {
    COMPRESSION(p1: unknown, p2: unknown, p3: unknown): unknown;
  }
  interface Viewer {
    setFilterOptions(filters: {
      filters: {
        processors: unknown
      }[],
      loadMode: string,
    }): unknown;
  }
}
```

Type missing for Filters

[image]

Demo for the OpenSeaDragon in plugin Filter  [image: Edit Initial OSD filter setu]